# data refresh enable in cloudapp

Tags: sql, database, powershell

Hi im trying to make a power shell script that can automate the enable for the data refresh schedule. can anyone help me with that?

```
    $rs2010 = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri "URL HERE" -Namespace 
    SSRS.ReportingService2010 -UseDefaultCredential;  
    $rs2010.Timeout = 3600000
    $schedules = $rs2010.ListSchedules("URL HERE");
    Write-Host "--- Disabled Schedules ---";  
    Write-Host "----------------------------------- ";  
    $schedules | WHERE { $_.ScheduleStatename -ne 'Ready' } 
    **strong text**
```

i have this that can output disabled schedules. i need help to make a powershell script that can enable the data refresh whenever its turn off.

/Adel

EDIT:::

so i got this code

```
    $rs2010 = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri 
    "http://url here/_vti_bin/ReportServer/ReportService2010.asmx" 
    -Namespace SSRS.ReportingService2010 -UseDefaultCredential;  
    $subscription = $rs2010.ListSubscriptions("http://url here/") 
    | Where-Object {$_.ScheduleStatename -ne "Ready" } ;  
    ForEach ($subscription in $subscriptions)  
             {  
             $rs2010.EnableDatasource($subscription.SubscriptionID);  
            $subscription | select subscriptionid, report, path
       }
```

but i get this error

Exception calling "EnableDataSource" with "1" argument(s): "The path of the item 'bda17ed4-81a5-40a6-bade-894ecde02373' is not valid. The full path must be less than 260 characters long; 
other restrictions apply. If the report server is in native mode, the path must start with slash. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.InvalidItemPathException:

Comment: So, what have you tried and what's stopping you from going further?

Comment: My guess is you have to change the next runtime.  I've done a fair amount of scripting of SSRS. Not of the scheduling portion though https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportservice2010.schedule.nextruntime.aspx

Comment: whats stopping me is that im a noob at powershell script. i dont know how i start the code.  @MathiasR.Jessen
i think that i could make a if statement,like if the data refresh is set to off then turn on or something like that?